# Combine Multiple Rows with same ID into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a query pulling values like:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, TITLE
FROM TABLE_X
```

To get results like:

```
ID  NAME  TITLE
----------------
01  Bob   Cat
02  Bob   Bat
03  Tom   Mat
```

I want to run a query to get the following results:

```
NAME  COUNT  TITLE
-----------------------
Bob   2      Cat, Bat
Tom   1      Mat
```

All I have is something like this:

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(ID), STUFF(TITLE)
FROM TABLE_X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STUFF syntax will be as shown in this below code to get your desired result-

```
SELECT B.NAME, COUNT(*) [COUNT],
STUFF((
    SELECT  ',' + A.TITLE 
    FROM TABLE_X A 
    WHERE A.NAME = B.NAME  
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') TITLE
FROM TABLE_X B
GROUP BY  B.NAME
```

Output is-

```
NAME    COUNT   TITLE
Bob     2       Cat,Bat
Tom     1       Mat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `NAME` and use the `STRING_AGG` aggregate function (starting with SQL Server 2017)

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(*) AS [COUNT], STRING_AGG(TABLE_X.TITLE, ', ') AS TITLE
FROM TABLE_X
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY NAME
```

Note that only the columns listed in the GROUP BY clause can appear as-is in the SELECT list. You must apply an aggregate function to all the others. I escaped the column alias `COUNT`, as this is a reserved word.

Comment: 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: This function was added in SQL Server 2017.

Comment: I have SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1 and that was the error they were giving me :/

Comment: It does not depend on the version of the Management Studio, it depends on the version of the DB Server.

Comment: That makes sense. Unfortunately I'm not sure about the server version, but I guess it's not 2017.

Comment: SELECT @@VERSION  to get the SQL-Server Version